# Run Grafana on HTTPS

Tags: https, grafana

I have installed [TIG (Telegraf, InfluxDB, Grafana)](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-tig-stack-telegraf-influxdb-and-grafana-on-ubuntu-1804/) for monitoring of server of https://cimall.ru:3000. But I can not run Grafana on port 3000. On site mirror http://cimall.cf:3000 it works quite well.

How I can run Grafana on HTTPS protocol?

Comment: This should not be a specific problem of grafana, but of the machine or the propbably used load balancer. Do you run other services over https on the affected machine, and do they work?

Comment: It was some problems in server, I asked hosing and they fixed it for me.